# Lighttpd - tomcat - reverse proxy - remote address

Tags: tomcat, lighttpd, reverse-proxy

I have a tomcat server proxied by lighttpd 1.4. The problem is, that HttpServleTRequest.getRemoteAddr returns localhost (127.0.0.1). Is there any way to configure Tomcat (6.0.29) or lighttpd to rewrite the remote address to its original value. (lighttpd in this version does not have AJP protocol support). Or have I to write my own servlet filter and do it somehow manually from headers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the header "X-Forwarded-For" in your tomcat app

See:
[http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModProxy](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs%3aModProxy)

[http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModExtForward](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs%3aModExtForward)